# Check Items Already exista in the Table using Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Select2 list and added multiple items to the table.But i wanted to check if items already exists in the table or not first and IF not only then add new item But below my code doesn't work.

In this code everytime it shows Not Found & add duplicate rows

HTML Part

```
<select id="select-product" multiple style="width: 300px">
</select>
```

Code

```
  $("#select-product").change(function () {
        debugger;
        var $option = $('#select-product option');
        if ($("#select-product option[value='ProductCode']").length > 0) {
            alert("Found");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Not Found");
        }

        $option.each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                debugger;
                var itm = $(this).is(':selected');
                var temp = $(this).attr('ProductCode');

                var row = '<tr>';
                row += '<td class="itmcode">' + $(this).attr('ProductCode') + '</td>';
                row += '<td class="itmname">' + $(this).text().replace(temp, " ") + '</td>';
                row += '<td class="unit">' + $(this).attr('Unit_UnitId') + '</td>';
                row += '<td class="retprice" dir="rtl" align="right">' + $(this).attr('RetailPrice') + '</td>';
                row += '<td class="col-md-1 inpqty" dir="rtl">' + '<input type="text" class="input-qty form-control col-md-3 center-block input-sm" data-id="' + $(this).val() + '" data-prod-id="' + $(this).attr('Value') + '">' + '</td>';
                row += '<td class="col-md-1 disc" dir="rtl">' + '<input type="text" class="input-disc form-control input-sm">' + '</td>';
                row += '<td class="tot" dir="rtl" align="right">0</td>';
                row += '<td class="imgdel"><img class="btn-img-del" src="../Images/delete.png" alt="" title="Delete" /></td>';
                row += '</tr>';

                table.append(row);
            }

        });


        $('#select-product').select2('data', null);



    });
```

Multiple Products Code

```
 function CallMultipleProducts() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Sales/GetMultipleProducts',
            contentType: "application/; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                debugger;
                if (msg._productlist.length > 0) {
                    debugger;
                    $.each(msg._productlist, function (index, item) {
                        debugger;
                        $('#select-product').append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("Value", item.ProductId)
                            .attr("RetailPrice", item.RetailPrice)
                            .attr("ProductCode", item.ProductCode)
                            .text((item.ProductCode) + " " + (item.ProductName))
                            );
                    });
                }
            }
            // error: AjaxError
        })
    }
```

Comment: could you provide the code where you have declared your select2 options.

Comment: Do you want to restrict the user to add duplicate products which are already in the select2 list?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have only `select` item with unique `id="select-product"` throughout your html.

Try below code, use `.find()`

```
if ($("#select-product").find("option[value='ProductCode']").length > 0) {
     alert("Found");
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you don't have multiple `select` box with same `id`? Can you please post a jsifddle link?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the below option to your select2 options if the element is input type="text",

```
$("#select-product").select2({
    createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {  if ($(data).filter(function() { return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0; }).length===0) {return {id:term, text:term};} }
});
```

If you are using `<select>` element, I'm afraid you can't use this option. You have to use `input` instead. You might find something useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674647/using-select2s-createsearchchoice-function).

Comment: Error: Option 'createSearchChoice' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.