# Allow user to self define the selected value in a select using Select2 and Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2

Select2 allows to improve standard `<select>` by applying on some style and feature.
I have to display Select2 styled dropdown list, custom binded with Knockout.

**It is a phone number list, and user could add some entries**.
**I want it to be editable**.

The user should be able to select an entry or type a new one wich can be used in the application (binded with `manager.selectedPhoneNumber`)

So, in the HTML:

```
<body>
<select id="list" data-bind="
    options: manager.getMyPhoneNumbers(),
    optionsValue: 'id',
    optionsText: 'text',
    customBinding_phoneNumbersEditableList: manager.selectedPhoneNumber
    ">
</select>
</body>
```

And in Javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customBinding_phoneNumbersEditableList = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                // initialize select2 with binded element
                $(element).select2({
                    //createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
                    //    if ($(data).filter(function () {
                    //        return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
                    //    }).length === 0) {
                    //        return {
                    //            id: term,
                    //            text: term
                    //        };
                    //    }
                    //},
                    formatResult: function (item) {
                        return buildSomePrettyString();
                    },
                    formatSelection: function (item) {
                        return buildSomePrettyString();
                    },
                    sortResults: function (results, container, query) {
                        return results;
                    }
                });
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) { }
        };
```

Uncomment the function `createSearchCoice` does not work. It causes an exception `Error: Option 'createSearchChoice' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.`

Someone could help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Select2's createSearchChoice function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674647/using-select2s-createsearchchoice-function)